# How to find white space position with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to find first white space position of a string.

Something like: `str_pos($content, ' ')` but I must do this with regular expression because str_pos don't detect every time white spaces in my content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
^(\S*)\s
```

which matches the non-whitespace characters before the first whitespace. Then you can find the length of the non-whitespace characters which will be the index of the first white-space.

```
if(preg_match('/^(\S*)\s/',$input,$m)) {
   echo "Position of first white-space is ",strlen($m[1]);
} else {
   echo "Now whitespace in $input";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

codaddict's solution works just fine. I just wanted to point out that the `preg_match()` and `preg_match_all()` functions can provide offset information in the `$matches` array if you set the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag. This way, you can simplify the regex to just `/\s/` and avoid calling `strlen()` like so:

```php
if (preg_match('/\s/', $input, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
   echo "Position of first white-space is ", $m[0][1];
} else {
   echo "No whitespace in $input";
}
```