# Order displayed items by id descending?

Tags: php, sql, yii, web

I have tried the codes here and on the forums and I cant seem to be able to get it working. I have a index page which displays my latest posts and just want to display them by id descending. I would also like to know as you can see below I am limiting my text below by characters, and I want it to be limited by number of words however when I tried, it would't display any text. Thanks here is my code.

**_view.php**

```
<div class="view">

 <? $this->pageTitle = "Latest Music"?>

<h4><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->id); ?>.
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->title); ?></h4>

<p><?php 
$charLimit = 680; 
$myText = CHtml::encode($data->text); 
$teaserText = substr($myText,0,$charLimit) . "..."; 
echo $teaserText; 
?></p>

<p><?php echo CHtml::link('View Article', array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
&nbsp
<?php echo CHtml::link('Update Article', array('update', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?></p>     
 </div>
```

**NewsController/actionIndex**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   $this->pageTitle = "$TitleP";
   $TitleP = print CHtml::encode($data->title);

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('news_model');
$this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,

    ));
}
```

**news_model**

```
class news_model extends CActiveRecord
{

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function tableName()
{
    return '{{news}}';
}

public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('title, text', 'required'),
       array('title', 'length', 'max'=>128),
           array('id', 'length', 'max'=>128),
           array('text', 'length', 'max'=>1500),
        array('title, text', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

public function relations()
{
    return array(
    );
}


public function attributeLabels()
{

    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'slug' => 'Slug',
        'text' => 'Text',
    );
}

public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
$criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
    $criteria->compare('text',$this->text,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an order to your `dataProvider` add a [`CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) as the 2nd parameter to your `CActiveDataProvider` constructor.

```
public function index(){
    ...
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('news_model',array('criteria'=>array('order'=>'id DESC')));//corrected answer
    ...
}
```

To limit the number of words (from [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5436653/428543))

```
$word_limit=100;

if (preg_match_all('/\s/', $text_to_shorten, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) && isset($m[0][$word_limit-1]) && $m[0][$word_limit-1][1]) 
        $shortened_text=substr($text_to_shorten, 0, $m[0][$word_limit-1][1]).'...';
else $shortened_text=$text_to_shorten;
echo $shortened_text;
```

P.S you have short open php tags at `<? $this->pageTitle = "Latest Music"?>`

> which are discouraged because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer however with the order I am getting `Property "CActiveDataProvider.order" is not defined.`

Comment: Also with the word limiter its displaying the whole text instead of shortening it?

`<?$text2 = CHtml::encode($data->text)?>


<p><?php 
$word_limit=50;
if (preg_match('/\s/', $text_to_shorten, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) && isset($m[0][$word_limit]) && $m[0][$word_limit]) 
        $shortened_text=substr($text2,$m[0][$word_limit]).'...';
else $shortened_text=$text2;
echo $shortened_text;
?></p>` 

any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to fix the order by it was because I had to put 'criteria'in see above.

Comment: I notices io issed one of the $text_to_shorten but it still didnit fix it it still displays the full text. `<?php $word_limit=50; if (preg_match('/\s/', $text2, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) && isset($m[0][$word_limit]) && $m[0][$word_limit]) $shortened_text=substr($text2,$m[0][$word_limit]).'...'; else $shortened_text=$text2; echo $shortened_text; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside, and addition to [topher's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490991/yii-framework-order-displayed-items-by-id-descending#15493215), if you **always** want to display posts in descending order throughout your whole application you can set a default scope to your model like so:

```
class news_model extends CActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function defaultScope()
    {
        $alias = $this->getTableAlias(false,false);
        return array(
            'order'=> "`$alias`.`id` DESC",
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

This will force all Active Record calls for your news model to order descending by id.

Of course, if you don't want this behaviour across the whole site, then I wouldn't bother adding in the default scope; just apply the order clause as and when needed ;)

Comment: Thanks, however I do just require it for one page but I am getting the error `Property "CActiveDataProvider.order" is not defined` with Topher example.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out the Order in the controller using the code below: Credits to @Topher

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   $this->pageTitle = "$TitleP";
   $TitleP = print CHtml::encode($data->title);

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('news_model', 
array('criteria'=>
              array('order' => ('id DESC')
              )));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. The answer has been corrected to match this.

Comment: @topher do you have a fix for the wordcount one as I mentioned on your answer as it doesnt seem to shorten the paragraph

Comment: sorry again. The correct method is `preg_match_all` not `preg_match`.